# Parse url encoded content to JSON

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to parse, with no sucess an url encoded body content like : `"data={\"event\":\"INBOX\",\"from\":\"3323230\",\"to\":\"43434343357\",\"text\":\"Example text"}"`

I'm doing : var myVar = JSON.parse(myUrlEncodedContenString)

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Looks correct but if not working can you try JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myUrlEncodedContenString));

Comment: In this case (  const myObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));  ) the result is an empty object { }

Comment: Can you paste the exact value that is coming from your API or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **basically** correct:

```
var myVar = JSON.parse(myUrlEncodedContenString);
```

**But your string is not a JSON object.** JSON object cannot start with "data=". The JSON object is only the path that starts after "data=". So first extract substring starting from the the index 5. Only following part is JSON:

```
{\"event\":\"INBOX\",\"from\":\"3323230\",...}
```

Furthermore, there is an error in your string. Escaping is missing on one place.

You have:

```
...\"Example text"}"
```

But it should be:

```
...\"Example text\"}"
```

Test that shows how it works (with escaping on the end fixed):

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
          var data = "data={\"event\":\"INBOX\",\"from\":\"3323230\",\"to\":\"43434343357\",\"text\":\"Example text\"}";
          var jsonEscaped = data.substring(data.indexOf("=") + 1);
          var result = JSON.parse(jsonEscaped);
          console.log(result);
          console.log(result.event);
          console.log(result.from);
          console.log(result.to);
          console.log(result.text);
    </script>
```

Comment: Agree...I suspect that to have an object it's necessary to parse the original string collecting the contained values.

Comment: In this case I got "[object Object]"

Comment: @GCoe: It means it works. See the browser console (press F12 on most browsers). You will see JSON object in your console. Your variable contains now a JavaScript object that corresponds to what is encoded in JSON. Now you can access the properties of this object, see "result.event" or "result.from" above. See example above. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Sorry ! You're correct and your solution worked fine. There was a mistake on my test. Thank you !